# Where did Tantra originate?

Tags: history, tantra

Modern Hinduism is a synthesis of different currents of thoughts. The two main streams are Vedic and Tantrik. Both these streams have many sub-schools. We are more or less aware of the Vedic scriptures and philosophies. But the philosophy, practices of Tantra are relatively shrouded in mystery. But before dealing with these, we need to know the fundamental stuff - like the original home of tantra. My question is where did Tantra originate?

Comment: No problem. Visit [help] articles to get familiar with the site.

Comment: i would say , Indus Valley

Answer (score 6):

Tantras have all emerged from Lord Shiva and not from a particular region or race of people. And, this is quite easy to prove. Also, the mass of Agamas and Nigamas is what constitutes the Tantras.

In my Guru Gita book, i find the following verse:

> Vandeham sacchidAnandam bhedAtitam srimadgurum |
>  **Agamo
>   nigamashchApi nirvAnashcha tridhAgamah** ||
>  TasmAdudhritya deveshi
>   gurugitA mayoditA | 110
>
> I praise the Guru who is OmkAra, who is of the form of eternal
>   knowledge, who is blissful, without attributes and magnificient. O
>   Deveshi, Agama, Nigama and NirvAna-- These are the three types of Agamas.
>   And, from which i have extracted and told to you, this Guru Gita,
>   which is known to be the essence of all of them (Agamas).

Now, the translator quotes from ViswasAra Tantram, the etymologies of the words- Agama and Nigama.

For Agama it is:

> **A**gatah shivavaktrebhyo **ga**tancha girijAsrutau **ma**tancha vAsudevasya tasmAdagammuchyate||
>
> That which comes from Shiva's mouth
>   (that is spoken by Lord Shiva) goes to GirijA's ears (that is heard by
>   Goddess PArvati) and which is approved by Vasudeva (that is Lord
>   Vishnu) is called **Agama.**

So, the Tantras which are spoken by Lord Shiva are called the Agamas and not some books which were written by the Kashmiris. For the Tantrikas, the Tantras are author-less and are AptaVAkya (words of God).

And, for Nigama the Nirukti is:

> **Ni**rgatam girijAvaktrAd **ga**tancha girishshrutau **ma**tancha vAsudevasya nigamah parikathyate ||
>
> That which has emerged from the mouth of PArvati, goes to Shiva's ears
>   and is approved by VAsudeva is **Nigama.**

NOw, very few Tantras are like that-which are spoken by Mother Goddess, but those which are are known as Nigama. In general Nigama refers to the Veda as well.

In the MahAnirvana Tantram's 1st chapter, Sri Adya also says that Lord Shiva created the Tantras:

> **Tvaya kritAni tantrAni** jivoddhAranahetave ||
>  NigamAgamajAtAni bhuktimuktikarAni cha | 1-49
>
> By Thee also have been composed for the good and liberation of men the
>   Tantras, a mass of Agamas and Nigamas, which bestow both enjoyment and
>   liberation, containing Mantras and Yantras and rules as to the sadhana
>   of both Devis and Devas. By Thee, too, have been described many forms
>   of Nyasa, such as those called srishti, sthiti (and sanghara)

Further, in KulArnava Tantram, Lord Shiva himself says that the five Amnayas (eastern, western, northern, southern and the higher ones) have all emerged from his five faces.

> **Mama panchamukhebhyashcha panchAmnayAh samudgatAh** |
>  Purvashcha
>   pashchimashchaiva dakshinashachottara stathA ||
>  UrdhAmnAyashcha
>   panchaite mokshamArgAh prakirttita || 3-7
>
> From my five faces emerged the five Amnayas. And these five Amanyas
>   are known to be the paths of liberation (MokshamArga)

The link between the five faces and the five Amnayas are as follows:

Name of the face- Name of the Amnaya that emerged from it

SadyojAta -PurvAmnAya (some say-Pashchima),
 VAmdeva-UttarAmnAya,
 Aghora- DakshinAmnAya,
 Tathpurusha- PurvAmnaya (some say Pashichama)
 IshAna- UrdhAmanya.

And, thereafter, these Tantras are propagated among mankind through the three Guru ParamparAs- Divyaugha (the lineage of Divine Gurus), Siddhaugha (the enlightened lineage like the several Rishis) and MAnavaugha (the lineage of human Gurus)

Comment: do guru geeta you mentioned is the same great guru geeta i am asking it because your word "my" made confusion in mind that is this my is devotion or something personal. don't take otherwise i am asking normally :)

Comment: Yes the same book i find this verse in.. @Fiercelord And why will i take it otherwise, it's just a normal query :)

Comment: No i thought that it don't hurt your emotion if were as my is used normally as my god my goddess etc so may be it sounds little wiered but its sometimes my usual way of talking :)
Well i will try to be little imformal from next time as you all are my brothers and friends. ;)

Comment: Oh.. ok yes that's just how i said it.. i could have said it differently as well like - In the Guru Gita book, i find this verse.. :D @Fiercelord

Comment: No no its alright @Rickross but thanks for understanding :)

Comment: Wow what a great answer